# Spring Retry is not allowing to stop the TC server Normally

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I am using spring retry template, when there is retry process is running, I am not able to stop the server. If I am trying to stop the server, It is saying tc server is not responding, would you like to terminate the server.

I followed the following way, but unfortunately the same result.

[How can I shutdown Spring task executor/scheduler pools before all other beans in the web app are destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603051/how-can-i-shutdown-spring-task-executor-scheduler-pools-before-all-other-beans-i)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `shutdownNow()` to interrupt any waiting (interruptible) threads.