# @EnableScheduling issues inside tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have this background service, recently added to my stable spring boot application that gets packaged as war and runs under tomcat in prod environment.

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling

public class MonitoringService {

  @Autowired
  SomeService someService;

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15*60*1000, initialDelay=30*1000)
  public void runPerodically() {      
      performChecks();  

  }

  @Bean
  public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(); 
  }  

}
```

Since this was added the tomcat seems behaving erratic and stuck at times and always produces thread dump when stopped such as

> INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-0.0.0.0-8083"]
>   2017-09-06 21:43:54
>   Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #119 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3ef4529000 nid=0x6496 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-7-thread-1" #67 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f3ea8653800 nid=0x7b28 waiting on condition [0x00007f3e9cf41000]

Are there any known issues with this approach or what is the right way to perform this task,

Comment: Is this working fine when you run it as standalone application?

Comment: yes, locally it runs as spring boot and seem to work fine.

Comment: I think there are two kind of situations, 1: the erratic behavior of tomcat without root cause, it could be related to `performChecks()` implementation .  2: the exception that you get when tomcat is stopped could be solved shutting down the task scheduler maybe this  post could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603051/how-can-i-shutdown-spring-task-executor-scheduler-pools-before-all-other-beans-i

Comment: Your `@Bean` method and `@EnableScheduling` should be on a `@Configuration` class (or your Spring Boot bootstrap class) not on a regular component.